# Jade access images from parent directory

Tags: node.js, express, parent-child, pug, directory-structure

I've got a big problem with Jade. Starting with my folder structure:

```
-root
--public
---asdq (<-- the users directories; asdq is just a test user)
----jellyfish.jpg (<-- the image; also just a test)
---www
----member.jade
```

So I'm working on a cloud-like service and I'm trying to show the images from here "/asdq/jellyfish.jpg" on the website which is in "/www/member.jade". So what did I allready tried?

1. Relative path: From node I passed the image path "../asdq/jellyfish.jpg" (and several variations of this like "../public" "/../../" etc.) which ends up Jade trying to find the folder "asdq" in "www". --> Nothing found no image displayed.
2. Absolute path: From node I passed the image path "C:/Users/Me/Desktop/ProjectX/public/asdq/jellyfish.jpg" which ends up Jade not even trying to find the picture. The node console logs no get for the image. --> No image displayed.
3. Changing the static folder in my app to "/public/www" and then starting with 1 and 2 again. Which ends up pretty the same way as before.

Btw. the passed paths are made dynamically as "usedirs" is just a placeholder for all the directories which users are able to create.

The big question is: How can I access the images which are in the parent's subfolder ? I'm going crazy on this problem as my researches allways ended up with : "Use '/.../' or '../' to gain access to the parent directories." And this just won't work ...

I hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: ../userdirs/userimages/file.jpg

Comment: oh i see .. no no "userimages" is just a placeholder fo the actual image .. I'll edit this :)